# Django models with same or similar fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I started to learn django and already have one question:
what kind of model creation are better if tables have similar fields?
1) Standart way form official tutorial like

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

As you see both models have same name and address fields. I found in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance the Multi-table ingeritance which works like this:
2)

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

As doc says: All of the fields of Place will also be available in Restaurant, although the data will reside in a different database table.

Well, is there any principal differences beteeen this two? And which one shall I use?

Comment: Abstract base class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you should use inheritance (solution 2).

Because the `Restaurant` is a special `Place`, which means Restaurant have field `name` and `address`, additionally, Restaurant have field `serves_hot_dogs` and `serves_pizza`.

Considering the above description, all solution is reasonable. But, `Restaurant` is a `Place`, `Restaurant` must can be processed as `Place`.
In solution1, `Restaurant` and `Place` are separated, you cannot process `Restaurant` as `Place`.(Just considering OOP)

In other side, in solution1, if I save a `Place` with address A, and I add a `Restaurant` with same address. I save same address twice in database, it leads to redundant and inconsistency.

---

This question is similar with the different of Composition and Inheritance in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference and you've just pasted link to documentation, which explains this difference.

`Restaurant` db table in (2) consists of two extra fields (`serves_hot_dogs` and `serves_pizza`) and a `ForeignKey` to record in `Place` db table.

As per the question which model you should use -- whatever suits you best. I usually use multi table inheritance in similar cases.

Before jumping into table inheritance please see: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager. I use it to limit the number of queries when dealing with multi table inheritance.